# returning all rows in table 1, when join most recent record in table 2

Tags: mysql

I've the following code, which pulls out the most recent row from a table called wwlassessments. 
It works, but what I'm trying to do is show all the rows matching the WHERE criteria in table, regardless of whether there's an entry in the wwlassessments table.

I've tried changing the 2nd JOIN to a LEFT JOIN, but this just provides thousands of inaccurate results.

I'm sure it's very simple, but I can't for the life of me work out what I need to change! Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT s.*,
      a.* 
FROM wwlstatements s
LEFT JOIN wwlassessments a ON a.id = s.id 
JOIN (SELECT n.id,n.pupilID,
              MAX(n.dateAchieved) AS max_achieved_date
         FROM wwlassessments n 
         where n.pupilID='114631705547'            
         GROUP BY n.id) y ON y.id = a.id 
                          AND y.max_achieved_date = a.dateAchieved        
                          WHERE s.`category`='Reading'
                          ORDER BY s.`statementID` ASC
```

Comment: Looks good to me - oh, see how you used an outer join for the first join, that should give you the hint

Comment: I've tried LEFT JOIN, JOIN, OUTER & INNER... no difference... Sorry, hint didn't work! ;-)

Comment: it's only returning rows from the first table, if there's a row matching the pupilID in the 2nd table... I think it's something to do with taking the pupilID out of the WHERE statement and using it in the ON section, but I can't get that working.

Comment: Left join works, but if you're still struggling see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: thanks for your comments, and I'll check out that link. With the query posted above, with the inclusion of pupilID in the WHERE clause, it isn't working. I know that LEFT JOIN is what's needed, but there's a reason why not all rows are showing from the LEFT table... pretty sure it's down to that WHERE clause... but I need that filter in there... must just be in the wrong place.

Comment: Got it.... for anyone else with the kind of issue... remove the WHERE clause as that and use that filter as part of the ON clause for the first LEFT JOIN>

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, but that doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: Indeed. It wasn't quite, but I can't find any way to paste solution code back here for others to benefit

Comment: You can answer your own question. And 'accept' it.